# Inserting at a specific point in a linked list

Tags: java

I am new to programming and I cannot figure out how to insert a node at a specific location in a linked list. It has to be inserted at position 3. Help with the logic for the insert would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void ins (Player p)
{
  PlayerNode current = head;
  PlayerNode previous = head;
  PlayerNode pn = new PlayerNode (new Player (p));
  int count=0;
  if (isEmpty())
  {
    pn.setNext(head);    
    head = pn;
    ++numberOfItems;

  }
  else
  {
    if (count != 3)
    {
      current = current.getNext();
      previous.setNext(pn);
      pn.setNext(current);

      ++count;
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: If it's homework, please tag it as such, it will help people give you relevant answers.

Comment: @bobby Are you building your own linked list or are you using Java's linked list?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use builtins?

[add(int index, E element)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
Node InsertNth(Node head, int data, int position) {

    Node node = head;
    if (position == 0){
        node = new Node();
        node.data = data;
        node.next = head;
        return node;
    }
    else {

        while(--position > 0){
            node = node.next;
        }
        Node i = node.next;
        node.next = new Node();
        node.next.data = data;
        node.next.next = i;
        return head;
    }
}
```